# How to get the oauth verifier code into my Android app

Tags: android, oauth, scribe

I am trying to use the scribe library to perform oauth authentication for my Android app with Flickr. The authUrl that is generated via the following code:

```
String authUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);
```

When I enter this URL in the browser, it takes me to the Flickr website where I am asked if User XYZ should grant permissions to my App and a Verifier code is issued. How do I programmatically extract this verifier code back into my application so that I can proceed with the authentication process. I don't want to ask the user to manually enter this code into the App.

Answer (score -1):

There's a repository at GitHub that does this whole process (automatically extracting the response you get) for FitBit. It should be easy to convert it for Flickr.

https://github.com/pugwonk/FitbitAndroidSample